# Event independence - Probability & Statistics

Tags: probability, statistics

Two boxes labelled **1** and **2** respectively contain 10 balls each (numbered from 1 to 10).

let **event A** be: An even ball is drawn from box 1,

let **event B** be: An odd ball is drawn from box 2, and finally

let **event C** be: The sum of the balls drawn from boxes 1 and 2 is even.

Are **A, B, C** independent events?

Comment: Yes as picking a ball from box 1 does not influence which ball you pick from box 2.

Comment: Thank you for your answer, I'm mainly concerned about independence between A & C, and B & C :-)

Comment: Interestingly each of the 3 events have a $\frac 12$ chance of occuring.

Comment: You have 'pairwise' independence, but not 'mutual' indep among all three events. For example, knowing A and B _determines_ C. However $P(AB)=P(A)P(B),$ etc.